# Java Socket Program and symbol cant find in DataInputStream class

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing a client server program and my program show me some error on the Socket object cant detect by the compiler, I have recheck it and there is not any misspell error or missing semicolon but it still show me the error.Beside, I also compare my program with some online socket programming tutorial and I found out my way is correct. I am very new to java socket programming

```
    try
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server : Configuring the port"+port);
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server : Waiting for client's connection");;
    while(true)
    {
      Socket socket = new Socket();
      socket = server.accept();
    }
   }
catch(IOException e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server : Nothing Found");
  }
    try
    {

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // get the input from client 
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  // Send the output to client 
        String word = "Connection Establish";  
        while(true)
        {
            word = output.readLine(); // read the message  
            output.println(word);  // display the message to client 
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server : Can't Connect To Server, Please Try Again");
    }

}
```

This is some of the portion of my program, the error show up in DataInputStream class because it cant find the symbol for the socket 

http://codepad.org/ISGe9eTx will provide the full program

Comment: So, you get an error. WHAT IS IT? Post the complete and exact error message. Tell us which line it refers to. Not reading the error message won't help you (and us) fixing the problem.

Comment: the error occur at all DataInputStream class which give me socket object not found

Comment: The error occur line 35/36 and line 40/41. sry for not providing clear instruction

Comment: That's not the *exat and complete* error message. That's you incorrect interpretation of the exact and complete error message. Have you defined a `socket` variable accessible from the try block? Do you know what variable scopes are?

Comment: `DataOutputStream` does not have a `println()` method. Your exception handling is poorly structured. Code that depends on the success of a try block should be inside that try block. The error here is just a simple scoping problem arising out of that poor coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `socket` outside the `try` block:

```
Socket socket = null;
try{
  ...
  while(true) {
    socket = server.accept();
  }
}
...
```

Comment: @ShinjiKagawa What problem would that be? You haven't described it in enough detail for anybody to know what it is, but this answer certainly corrects an error in your code.

Comment: thank you to all of you, I solved all the error message ady